# Setting a useReducer dispatch in child component is not working?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

here's the code
i want the button in App.tsx to be enabled only if enableNotification is true
I can put the api call in App.tsx and make it work but, we cannot do that as am trying to keep the App.tsx with less number of codes as possible.

```
App.tsx

const [enableNotification, setEnableNotification] = useReducer((open) => !open,true);

export default function App() {
    return (
        {enableNotification && <Button>
            <div className="App">
                < ChildComponent setEnableNotification={setEnableNotification} >< /ChildComponent >
            </div>
        </Button>}
  );
}

ChildComponent.tsx


export default function ChildComponent(props:any) {
    
     const getDetailsAPI = () => {
      const result = await axiosInstance().get('API Call');
      if(result.status === 200){
           if(result.data.length == 0){
              props.setEnableNotification;
            }
      }
    }

    return (
        <Dialog>
            <div className="App">
                {getDetailsAPI()}
            </div>
        </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: props.setEnableNotification(previousState=>!previousState); try this .bettter create codesandbox .its easy to debug us

Comment: @JohnLobo what should be the previousState in my case?

Comment: whatever i state .if not you can set value true or false.just guessing'  or props.setEnableNotification(true);